# Wrong outpup JavaScript in Groovy

Tags: groovy

When I execute the script Groovy(Method Stop)  my Output is Result, but  the code of the script in result is wrong, how is show it below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      <getValues>
        <alert>hola</alert>
      </getValues>
      <function>getValues</function>
    </script>
```

when I am waiting for something like this:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
          function getValues() {
                    alert('hola');
                }
        </script>
```

Is There a way to print the code JavaScript properly in Groovy ?

Result

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      <getValues>
        <alert>hola</alert>
      </getValues>
      <function>getValues</function>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id='main'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>
          <p>Parameters marked with 
            <font style='color:red'>*</font> are required.
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Year:
          <font style='color:red'>*</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name='Year_selection'>
            <option value='2008'>2008</option>
            <option value='2007'>2007</option>
            <option value='2006'>2006</option>
            <option value='2005'>2005</option>
            <option value='2004'>2004</option>
            <option value='2003'>2003</option>
            <option value='2002'>2002</option>
            <option value='2001'>2001</option>
            <option value='2000'>2000</option>
            <option value='1999'>1999</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>IsMale: 
          <font style='color:red'>*</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type='CHECKBOX' id='IsMale' title='' value='IsMale' />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type='button' value='OK' onclick='javascript:getValues();' />
    <input type='button' value='Cancel' />
  </body>
</html>
```

Script Groovy

```
 import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
def stop(){
   return generate_html_with_markupbuilder()
}
String generate_html_with_markupbuilder() {

    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def html = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    html.html {
        head {
               script{
                function getValues() {
                    alert('hola');
                }
           }
        }
        body(id: "main") {

                table {
                    tr{
                        td(colspan:2){
                             p {
                                    mkp.yield "Parameters marked with "
                                    font style:"color:red" , "*"
                                    mkp.yield " are required."

                                }
                         }
                    }

                    tr {
                        td{
                            mkp.yield "Year:"
                            font style:"color:red" , "*"
                        }
                        td{
                            select(name: 'Year_selection') {
                            option(value: "2008", "2008")
                            option(value: "2007", "2007")
                            option(value: "2006", "2006")
                            option(value: "2005", "2005")
                            option(value: "2004", "2004")
                            option(value: "2003", "2003")
                            option(value: "2002", "2002")
                            option(value: "2001", "2001")
                            option(value: "2000", "2000")
                            option(value: "1999", "1999")

                      } 
                        } 
                    }
                    tr{
                        td{
                            mkp.yield "IsMale: "
                            font style:"color:red" , "*"
                        }
                        td{
                            input(type:"CHECKBOX", id:"IsMale", title:"", value:"IsMale") 
                        }
                    }
                }


                input(type:"button", value:"OK" , onclick:'javascript:getValues();')
                input(type:"button", value:"Cancel")

        }
    }
    writer.toString()
}
this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need:

```
       script{
            mkp.yieldUnescaped '''
                function getValues() {
                    alert('hola');
                }'''
       }
```